# NUllPointerException on TDTM Trigger

Tags: trigger, npsp

I have a TDTM trigger on the Case object which does some simple operations. Problem is, all contact-related fields appear to be null, so I get a nullPointerException error when trying to update one of those fields.

Here's the code:

```
global class TDTM_UNITA_Case extends npsp.TDTM_Runnable {
    global override npsp.TDTM_Runnable.DmlWrapper run(List<SObject> newlist,
                                             List<SObject> oldlist,
                                             npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action triggerAction,
                                             Schema.DescribeSObjectResult objResult) {
    npsp.TDTM_Runnable.dmlWrapper dmlWrapper = new npsp.TDTM_Runnable.DmlWrapper();
   if (triggerAction == npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action.AfterInsert || triggerAction == npsp.TDTM_Runnable.Action.AfterUpdate)
        {
            //List<Case> listNewCase = [select id, contactid, UNITA_Case_Type__c, Status, CreatedDate,contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c from case where id in : Trigger.New];
            List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
            for(Case newCase : (list<Case>)newlist)
            {
                // data ultimo esito telemarketing outbound
                // max data contatto dei case con case type = OUT-Telemarketing, status= Completed.      
                // usato nel WF welcome oneoff per check se il donatore ha un esito della conversion call   
                system.debug ('$$$$ aaaa newCase.UNITA_Case_Type__c = ' + newCase.UNITA_Case_Type__c);
                system.debug ('$$$$ newCase.Status = ' + newCase.Status);
                system.debug ('$$$$ newCase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c = '+ newCase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c);
                system.debug ('$$$$ newCase.CreatedDate.date() = ' + newCase.CreatedDate.date());
                system.debug ('$$$$ newCase.Contact.Name = ' + newCase.Contact.Name);


                
                if (newCase.UNITA_Case_Type__c == 'OUT-TELEMARKETING' && newCase.Status == 'Completed')
                {
                    if (null == newcase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c ||  newCase.CreatedDate > newcase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c )
                    {
                        system.debug('createdDate.date: '  + newcase.CreatedDate.date());
                        system.debug('newCase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c = '+ newCase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c);
                        newcase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c = Date.newInstance(newCase.CreatedDate.year(), newCase.CreatedDate.month(), newCase.CreatedDate.day());//newCase.CreatedDate.date();
                        system.debug ('$$$$ 1 aggiorno UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c con ' + newcase.contact.UNITA_Data_Ultimo_Out_TMK__c);
                        //update newcase.contact;
                        contactsToUpdate.add(newcase.Contact);
                    }
                }
            }
            //update contactsToUpdate;
            dmlWrapper.objectsToUpdate.addAll((list<SObject>)ContactsToUpdate);
        }
                                                 
   return      dmlWrapper;                                         
 }

}
```

As you can see from the debugs, contact related fields appear null:

[image]

But they're actually not. Here's the full error:

> execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException:
> Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.TDTM_UNITA_Case.run: line
> 30, column 1 (System Code)

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: what was the result for the contact fields when you tried SOQL with 'listNewCase'?

Comment: newlistcase: (Case:{Id=5003O00000AU5PfQAL, ContactId=0033O00000lim0MQAQ, UNITA_Case_Type__c=OUT-TELEMARKETING, Status=Completed, CreatedDate=2022-01-11 16:31:40})

Comment: You can't have access to parent fields inside a trigger without querying the object. This is totally normal.

Comment: I've linked this question to our canonical QA that covers this issue.